# Irreducible polynomial over Q without Einstein's criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I try to prove the next statement:

For $n>=0$ show that $5x^n - 1$ is irreducible over Q[x].

I have been doing some research and find einstein's statement but it doesn't fix the problems and the rest of the examples that I found on this page are for a very specific polynomial. I think that probably the fact of not repeated roots can help but I don't know the strategy to prove this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can view $x^n-\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: Do you  mean Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: @Infinity_hunter That isn't sufficient. You could have no rational roots, but still split into quadratic/cubic terms.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Oh,Yes you are correct

Comment: The reciprocal of the polynomial $f(x)=5x^n-1$ is
$$\tilde{f}(x)=x^5f(1/x)=-x^5+5,$$ which is irreducible by Eisenstein. It is easy to see that a polynomial with non-zero constant term is irreducible if and only if its reciprocal is.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Hi, thank u for your help it was very helpful. I already proof the Einsensteion criteria in order to use it in my proof but for the statement  "a polynomial with the non-zero constant term is irreducible if and only if its reciprocal is" I don't get it because  I think the direction <= isn't true, take for example (taking into a count f*=gh) h(x) be irreducible with nonzero constant term and let f(x)=xh(x). Then (f∗)∗=h(x) and ((f∗)∗)∗=f∗, so f∗ is irreducible even though f is not. Thanks again!

Comment: You need to have non-zero constant coefficient as mentioned by Jyrki (the $xh(x)$ has zero constant coefficient).